# Custumize TOC only for the appendix part

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, hyperref, page-numbering, appendices

I am currently writing in `article` class and I would like to do something really specific in my toc. Currently it looks like this: [image]

I got the phrase "Appendices" in there by using

```
    \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}\appendix
```

This is almoast what I was going for but not quite. Since "Appendices" is not really  a section of its own, I would like to remove the page number that it gets. Also I would like the white space between the last (real) section and the word "Appendices" to be slightly yet noticeably larger than it is between the other  entries.

It is probably  clear to you that I'm trying to implement something to my toc that makes a clear visual distiction between the main part and the rest of the document. If someone knows a better/easier way to do this, than  by the means I'm trying; please do let me know.

Here's a MWE:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[dutch]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amstext,amsthm,amssymb,graphicx,mathtools,scrextend,xcolor}
    \usepackage{babelbib}
    \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Centrale...}
    \subsection{De stelling...}
    \section{De Brauer}
    \section{Quasi-...}

    \newpage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\rule{0pt}{5ex}Appendices \color{white}}\appendix
    \section{Nulpunten...}
    \section{Formele...}
    \end{document}
```

**Edit:** The [answer provided by Steven B. Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207709/44572) works almost perfectly, except that it doesn't seem to work in combination whith the `hyperref` package. Excluding the `hyperref` package is not an option, so I'm adding compatibility with `hyperref` to my question.

Comment: not tested: try substituting "part" for "section".

Comment: @barbarabeeton: It's *the* article class, according to the OP, so there is no `part`. `\phantomsection\addtocontents{toc}{Appendices}\appendix` could help

Comment: Both suggestions did not work. Substituting "part" only made the font size bigger. Leaving `{section}` out gave an error.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- before i commented, i checked `article.cls`.  it does contain lines like `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}`, so `part` *is* defined.  what i wasn't sure about is whether it would produce the desired output.  which is why i wrote a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Alright, I did not check it, since I was rather sure that `part` is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REVISED APPROACH (using `\contentsline` revision, to handle `hyperref`)

With this revision, I totally reworked the approach.  The first key was the invocation of the phantom section as

```
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{Z}{%
      \protect\rule{0pt}{5ex}{\Large Appendices}}
```

to use type sectioning type `Z` instead of `section`.  To handle this possibility, I had to redefine `\contentsline` as follows:

```
\renewcommand\contentsline[4]{%
  \ifx Z#1\relax\svcontentsline{section}{#2}{}{#4}\else
    \svcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}\fi
}
```

In this way, if a `Z` is detected as the first argument of `\contentsline`, it invokes `\svcontentsline{section}{#2}{}{#4}` with a blank argument `#3`, which is the page number.  If `#1` is not a `Z`, the traditional invocation is made.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\providecommand\phantomsection{}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{appndx}
\newcommand\anappendix[2][x]{
  \clearpage
  \refstepcounter{appndx}
  \setcounter{section}{\arabic{appndx}}
  \renewcommand\thesection {\appendixname~\Alph{appndx}.}
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}
  \renewcommand\thesubsection {\Alph{appndx}.\@arabic\c@subsection}
  \setcounter{paragraph}{0}
  \setcounter{subparagraph}{0}
  \setcounter{equation}{0}
  \setcounter{figure}{0}
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{appndx}-\@arabic\c@figure}
  \setcounter{table}{0}
  \renewcommand\thetable{\Alph{appndx}-\arabic{table}}
  \renewcommand\theequation {\Alph{appndx}-\arabic{equation}}
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}
  \def\appendixtitle{\appendixname~\Alph{appndx}. #2}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}\appendixtitle
  \if p#1\vspace*{\fill}\fi
  {\centering\theappendix\appendixtitle\par}
  \if p#1\vspace*{\fill}\clearpage\fi
}
\newcommand\theappendix[1]{
  \section*{#1}
}
\let\svcontentsline\contentsline
\renewcommand\contentsline[4]{%
  \ifx Z#1\relax\svcontentsline{section}{#2}{}{#4}\else
    \svcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}\fi
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Centrale ...}
\subsection{De stelling...}
\section{De Brauer...}
\section{Quasi-algebraic...}

\clearpage
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{Z}{%
  \protect\rule{0pt}{5ex}{\Large Appendices}}

\anappendix{Nulpunten...}
xyz
\anappendix{Formele...}
xyz

\end{document}
```

[image]

ORIGINAL APPROACH (using white page number)

Obviously, without an MWE on the OP's part, I had to construct my own version of appendices, nonetheless, the following works (in `article` class).  The key line:

```
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{%
  \protect\rule{0pt}{5ex}{\Large Appendices}\color{white}}
```

The `\color{white}` makes sure the page number is printed in white.  The protected `\rule` adds header space above the name `Appendices`.  The `\Large` makes it the same size as `Contents`, though perhaps you might change that to suit.

[As noted by OP, Doesn't quite Work] with `hyperref`.  Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\providecommand\phantomsection{}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{appndx}
\newcommand\anappendix[2][x]{
  \clearpage
  \refstepcounter{appndx}
  \setcounter{section}{\arabic{appndx}}
  \renewcommand\thesection {\appendixname~\Alph{appndx}.}
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}
  \renewcommand\thesubsection {\Alph{appndx}.\@arabic\c@subsection}
  \setcounter{paragraph}{0}
  \setcounter{subparagraph}{0}
  \setcounter{equation}{0}
  \setcounter{figure}{0}
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{appndx}-\@arabic\c@figure}
  \setcounter{table}{0}
  \renewcommand\thetable{\Alph{appndx}-\arabic{table}}
  \renewcommand\theequation {\Alph{appndx}-\arabic{equation}}
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}
  \def\appendixtitle{\appendixname~\Alph{appndx}. #2}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}\appendixtitle
  \if p#1\vspace*{\fill}\fi
  {\centering\theappendix\appendixtitle\par}
  \if p#1\vspace*{\fill}\clearpage\fi
}
\newcommand\theappendix[1]{
  \section*{#1}
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Centrale ...}
\subsection{De stelling...}
\section{De Brauer...}
\section{Quasi-algebraic...}

\clearpage
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{%
  \protect\rule{0pt}{5ex}{\Large Appendices}\color{white}}

\anappendix{Nulpunten...}
xyz
\anappendix{Formele...}
xyz

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How geniously simple. In my case however the `\color{white}` command doesn't do anything. I've added a MWE. Can you perhaps  see why it's not working.

Comment: @gebruiker You are right that it does not work with `hyperref`.  I'll give it some more thought, but I am not optimistic.

Comment: I've noticed that colouring does apply to "Appendices" in combination with `hyperref`, just not the page number... :(

Comment: @gebruiker Please see revision.

Comment: Thank you, that totally did it. One important thing that should perhaps be mentioned is that `\let\svcontentsline\contentsline
\renewcommand\contentsline[4]{%
  \ifx Z#1\relax\svcontentsline{section}{#2}{}{#4}\else
    \svcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}\fi
}
` should be uesed after `\usepackage{hyperref}` or else you'll get an error. Also when I tried to run it, I didn't need to load the `ifthen`-package...